# flutter: perform size error while building the ui?

Tags: dart, flutter

In this code I am trying to output a list of pickerCards which resmeble Container with added properties. While trying to do so. I got this error I tried to specify the height by inserting all the widget into a container with specified height but sadly it didn't work. any help will be appreciated. 
find the attached code

```
class PackageScreenState extends State<PackageScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Choose package"),
        ),
        body: 
          StreamBuilder<UnmodifiableListView<Package>>(
              stream: subscriptionBloc.package,
              builder:
                  (_, AsyncSnapshot<UnmodifiableListView<Package>> packages) {
                if (packages.hasData == true) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                           shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: packages.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return PackageContainer(
                          titleText: packages.data[index].name,
                          price: packages.data[index].price,
                          subtitleText: packages.data[index].description,
                          onPressed: null,
                        );
                      }));
                } //if end statment
                else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }

        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `shrinkWrap` property to your `ListView.builder`

```
  shrinkWrap: true
```

Comment: Ooh , it workeed. However, I was looking forward that page will be scrollable but it turns out to be static one, that  I put it in listview in order to be able to scroll it but nothing changed.. check the edited code

Comment: hmm I don't understand , but you already have a ListView which is scrollable

Comment: I know that but after running the code( shown above) the page doesnot scroll even I wrap it all in listview.

Comment: did you add : shrinkWrap ?  why you add  : ListView( children: <Widget>[ as a Container of your ListView.builder?

Comment: Yes I did and it solved that error I was asking about. However, I was expecting that my view will be a scrollable one, but it turns out that's not and I really cant get it why even I am wrapping the whole body in listview in order to be scrollable

Comment: Wrap your ListView.builder inside a Container or SizedBox with fixed height size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  then  remove  shrinkWrap: true,

Comment: you were right. I donot have to wrap it in listview again. I only put the streambuilder into the body directly. check the edited code.  thank lots for help